# Why there is continuous variation in output frequency of a Hitachi Inverter (L100 Series)?

Tags: inverter, potentiometer, vfd

I am using a Hitachi L100 Series inverter and its frequency source is Keypad Potentiometer. During run it is continuously changing the output frequency which is displayed on the Operator Display Screen. I want to have the fixed speed after i set it from the keypad Potentiometer. Please tell me why it is varying and how can i reduce it or make it to run at constant speed.
Note: The variation is small (maximum of +- 0.7 )

Comment: Maybe it's broken?

Comment: what? the potentiometer?

Comment: Try to use the keypad buttons to set the frequency instead of potentiometer and see if there is a difference.

Comment: Hmm Ok Let me try

Comment: It didn't have the option of setting the speed through keypad buttons. But there is a third option for source frequency which is a constant frequency and it takes the value from a parameter. I used that and it solved my problem. But still I don't know why was it varying up and down when the source frequency was potentiometer.

Answer (score 1):

It may simply be noise in the analog-to-digital conversion. The drive has to read the input from the pot, convert it to digital, and then use that to determine the frequency. A variation of a couple tenths of a percent may not be unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this done to reduce audible noise. It's often less irritating to spread the noise across a spectrum than it is to output a single tone.